# Everytime I deploy to heroku I get a Timeout error

Tags: django, heroku

I've been using Heroku for over a year now to deploy my Django app.

Suddenly though (without any major changes) everytime I push to Heroku, I'm getting the error, `(Utils::TimeoutError)`

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:appname.git'
```

It happens everytime, but at different stages of installing all the packages in my `requirements.txt` file.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for the python build pack talk about this

> Build Timeout
>
> This is normally caused by a very large number of dependencies being
>   installed at the same time.
>
> Sometimes, this is caused by a Python interpreter upgrade. In this
>   case, you have two options:
>
> Add a runtime.txt file to your repository that specifies the existing
>   version of python you're using (e.g. python-2.7.3). Learn more.
>
> Install all of your dependencies again. I'd recommend pushing once
>   with only half of your dependencies, then once again with all of them.
>   Then you won't hit the timeout.
>
> Once they are installed, they are cached, so you shouldn't run into
>   this again.

You can see more here https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/wiki/Troubleshooting#build-timeout.

Comment: Thanks. You're right -- installing the dependencies in batches worked.