# Heroku Django App deployment timeout

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django, heroku

I have been deploying this django app to heroku several times over the past few months. Today I'm hitting a timeout while deploying even though I haven't changed any configuration. The `Cleaning up..` step takes a long time and then it just fails on `Collecting static files` step. Has anyone faced this issue recently? Is it an infrastructure problem or python version change or something else?

```
      Cleaning up...
-----> Collecting static files

 !     Timed out compiling Python app (15 minutes)
 !     See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#time-limit

Auto packing the repository for optimum performance.
To git@heroku.com:x.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:x.git'
```

Comment: Is the `collectstatic` command waiting on user input? You can pass `--noinput` so it doesn't prompt for anything. [Link to the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic)

Comment: No, I had disabled collectstatic on heroku. The configuration might have changed or something. I reset it to disabled and along with setting an explicit python runtime and removing some pip dependencies that I was loading externally. Things seem to be working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that got this to work.

[Disable collectstatic](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)

```
$ heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
$ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

[Add explicit python runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes). In my case I just stuck to the working version I had i.e python-2.7.4

Remove unnecessary external dependencies from your `requirements.txt`. Now this can be application specific but I had a custom `pil` and a django module that I did not really need being installed externally (from bitbucket). This never was a problem before. But I removed them just in case of this - [Everytime I deploy to heroku I get a Timeout error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173467/everytime-i-deploy-to-heroku-i-get-a-timeout-error)