# Getting error when deploying my shiny application on heroku

Tags: r, heroku, shiny, heroku-cli

I am getting an error Timed out running buildpack R (shiny) Push failed while deploying my shiny application to heroku. My project structure is good. There is no error in the log. I am using the heroku cli to deploy the application.

This is the git repository:
https://github.com/akshaybholee/CountryProfileHeroku

this is my git remote

```
git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/countryprofile.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/countryprofile.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/akshaybholee/CountryProfileHeroku.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/akshaybholee/CountryProfileHeroku.git (push)
```

I ran this command to deploy the application:

```
git push heroku main
```

Here is the log (It's not the full log as it is too big to post here):

```
Enumerating objects: 73, done.
Counting objects: 100% (73/73), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (68/68), done.
Writing objects: 100% (73/73), 307.61 KiB | 4.39 MiB/s, done.
Total 73 (delta 21), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r.git
remote: -----> R (shiny) app detected
remote: -----> Installing R
remote:        Version 4.2.1 will be installed on heroku-22 stack.
remote: -----> Downloading buildpack archives from AWS S3
remote:        Downloading https://heroku-buildpack-r.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/heroku-buildpack-r-22-4.2.1-deploy.tar.gz
remote:        Downloading https://heroku-buildpack-r.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/heroku-buildpack-r-22-4.2.1-shiny.tar.gz
remote:        Setting up build environment
remote:        Downloading https://heroku-buildpack-r.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/heroku-buildpack-r-22-4.2.1-chroot.tar.gz
remote: -----> Configuring build environment...
remote:
remote:  #     WARNING: Use of the Aptfile file is NOT recommended and will be deprecated in future.
remote:
remote:        For greater control and flexibility consider using the Heroku
remote:        container stack together with the heroku-docker-r implementation.
remote:        See https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-docker-r for more information.
remote:
remote:        W: No sandbox user '_apt' on the system, can not drop privileges
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote:        Building dependency tree...
remote:        Reading state information...
remote:        The following additional packages will be installed:
remote:          default-libmysqlclient-dev gdal-data hdf5-helpers libaec-dev libaec0
remote:          libarmadillo-dev libarmadillo10 libarpack2 libarpack2-dev libblosc-dev
remote:          libblosc1 libboost-dev libboost1.74-dev libcfitsio-dev libcfitsio-doc
remote:          libcfitsio9 libcharls-dev libcharls2 libfreexl-dev libfreexl1 libfyba-dev
remote:          libfyba0 libgdal30 libgeos-c1v5 libgeos-dev libgeos3.10.2 libgeotiff-dev
remote:          libgeotiff5 libgif-dev libgif7 libhdf4-0-alt libhdf4-alt-dev libhdf5-103-1
remote:          libhdf5-cpp-103-1 libhdf5-dev libhdf5-fortran-102 libhdf5-hl-100
remote:          libhdf5-hl-cpp-100 libhdf5-hl-fortran-100 libjson-c-dev libkml-dev
remote:          libkmlbase1 libkmlconvenience1 libkmldom1 libkmlengine1 libkmlregionator1
remote:          libkmlxsd1 libminizip-dev libminizip1 libnetcdf-dev libnetcdf19 libnspr4
remote:          libnss3 libodbc2 libodbccr2 libodbcinst2 libogdi-dev libogdi4.1
remote:          libpoppler-dev libpoppler-private-dev libpoppler118 libproj-dev libproj22
remote:          libqhull-dev libqhull-r8.0 libqhull8.0 libqhullcpp8.0 librttopo-dev
remote:          librttopo1 libsnappy1v5 libspatialite-dev libspatialite7 libsqlite3-0
remote:          libsqlite3-dev libsuperlu-dev libsuperlu5 libsz2 liburiparser-dev
remote:          liburiparser1 libwebp-dev libxerces-c-dev libxerces-c3.2 proj-bin proj-data
remote:          unixodbc-common unixodbc-dev

remote:        installing to /app/R/site-library/00LOCK-spam/00new/spam/libs
remote:        ** R
remote:        ** data
remote:        *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
remote:        ** demo
remote:        ** inst
remote:        ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
remote: -----> Timed out running buildpack R (shiny)
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to countryprofile.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/countryprofile.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/countryprofile.git'
```

Please help me solve this.

Comment: I don't know for sure what's causing the build timeout (presumably though, the project is too big for the build machine). It's definitely not a *Git* issue though: you get the rejection from Git because Heroku told Git to reject the push. The problem is entirely somewhere within Heroku and/or R-and-Shiny.

Comment: Thank you torek. I have deployed the application through container finally. Using a well constructed dockerfile and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this and doesn't want to build a docker container, following the directions here worked for me:

[Everytime I deploy to heroku I get a Timeout error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173467/everytime-i-deploy-to-heroku-i-get-a-timeout-error)

e.g. 'Install all of your dependencies again. I'd recommend pushing once with only half of your dependencies, then once again with all of them. Then you won't hit the timeout.

Once they are installed, they are cached, so you shouldn't run into this again.'